# Issues reading text from a file. Getting double reads

Tags: c++, file-io

Hello friends at stackoverflow!

I have written a program that saves 3 strings to a textfile. The code to write is:

```
void my_class::save_file(const char* text) {
    for(auto ad: ad_list) {
        std::ofstream outputFile;
        outputFile.open(text, std::ios::app);
        if (outputFile.is_open()) {
            outputFile << ad.string1 << "|" << ad.string2 << "|" << ad.string3 << "|" << std::endl;
            outputFile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the file with the content:

```
string1|string2|string3|
   <- //extra line here
```

When i read from this file I do it with the following function:

```
void my_class::read_file(const char* text) {
    // read file to stringsteam
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::ifstream fp (text);
    if (fp.is_open()) {
        ss << fp.rdbuf(); 
    }
    fp.close();
    string file_contents = ss.str();

    // split to lines
    auto lines = splitString(file_contents, "\n");

    // split to parts
    for (auto ad_text: lines) {   // <-- this is the possibly the issue
        auto ad_parts = splitString(ad_text, "|");
        string string1 = ad_parts[0];
        string string2 = ad_parts[1];
        string string3 = ad_parts[2];
        auto new_class = MyClass(string1, string2, string3);
        //Adds (push_back) the class to its vector
        add_class(new_class);
    }
}

vector<string> my_class::splitString(string text, string delimiter) {
    vector<string> parts;
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = 0;
    while((end = text.find(delimiter, start)) != std::string::npos) {
        size_t length = end - start;
        parts.push_back(text.substr(start, length));
        start = end + delimiter.length();
    }
    start = end + delimiter.length();
    size_t length = text.length() - start;
    parts.push_back(text.substr(start, length));

    return parts;
}
```

Result:

```
string1|string2|string3|
string1|string2|string3|
```

I'm pretty sure this copy is a result of the new line left behind by the write function. The read function splits the text into lines, and that would be 2 lines.
I am currently splitting the lines in this loop "for (auto ad_text: lines)", and what I want to do is basically ( lines - 1 ). I do not understand how I can do that with the way I am interating through the for loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `start = end + delimiter.length();` At the end of the loop, `end == std::string::npos` (by loop condition), and `std::string::npos` is defined as `size_t(-1)`. You add 1 to that, and end up with `start == 0`, then add the whole `text` as the last element to `parts`. What did you hope to achieve with `start = end + delimiter.length()`?

Comment: Thank you! I feel so dumb now. Yes I was splitting it an extra time for a test I had done previously. This fixed my issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **simplify** your `splitString` function to look like below. Note the second parameter to `splitString` is a `char` now and not a `std::string`.

```
//note the second parameter is a char and not a string now 
vector<string> splitString(string text, char delimiter) {
    vector<string> parts;
    std::string words;
    std::istringstream ss(text);
    while(std::getline(ss, words,delimiter ))
    {
         parts.push_back(words);
    }
   
    return parts;
}
```

For the above modification to work you have to *make 2 additional changes*:

**Change 1**: Replace `auto lines = splitString(file_contents, "\n");` to:

```
auto lines = splitString(file_contents, '\n');
```

**Change 2**: Replace  `auto ad_parts = splitString(ad_text, "|");` to:

```
 auto ad_parts = splitString(ad_text, '|');
```